# Z-index issue in child and sibling elements

Tags: html, css, css-position

I'm having three `div` in my page.

- One parent (`z-index: 5`)
- One sibling (of the parent) (`z-index: 10`)
- One child (of the parent) (`z-index: 11`)

All the `div` are using `position: fixed` property.

My problem is the stacking order of the three elements.

I'm using the 'sibling'  `div` as a freeze layer in the app.

I want the sibling `div` to be positioned between the parent and its child `div`

AFAIK, by using the `position: fixed` property, we can position the divs anywhere in a page and use any stacking order.

But it's not working for my current scenario.

Please find the attached code:

```css
.fixed {
  position: fixed;
}

.outer {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: yellow;
  z-index: 5;
}

.child {
  width: 200px;
  height: 30px;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  background: red;
  z-index: 11;
  color: #fff;
}

.sibling {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  z-index: 10;
}
```

```html
<div class="fixed outer">
  <div class="fixed child">
    I want this div to be on top
  </div>
</div>
<div class="fixed sibling">

</div>
```

Comment: you only way is to remove positiion:fixed and z-index from the parent element to be able to bring the child behind : https://jsfiddle.net/o4Lewp76/

Comment: I'm sorry but in your fiddle, the `.sibling` freeze layer is nowhere visible because it is behind the `.parent` element. I want the `.sibling` stacked between the `.child` and `.parent`.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/xkvq16Lu/ simply adjust z-index without touching the parent

Comment: You have changed the position of the parent to `absolute`. I cannot proceed with this answer as I NEED all the three divs to be of `position: fixed`. And IMHO I don't think this is a duplicate question of what you've mentioned !

Comment: as I said, if you keep position:fixed you cannot do this, it's impossible. The duplicate is a canonical duplicate explaining all what you need to know about stacking context, painting order, z-index, etc. If you read it carefully you will understand why what you want is simply impossible

Comment: Alright then. I'll look into it. Thanks for your time !

Answer (score 0):

Can you change your html structure like this ? It is working then.

```
<div class="fixed outer">
  <div class="fixed child">
    I want this div to be on top
  </div>
  <div class="fixed sibling">

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I cannot modify the HTML structure.

Answer (score 0):

Your assumption is not correct.

`position: fixed` creates a new [stacking context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context#The_stacking_context)

> A stacking context is formed, anywhere in the document, by any element in the following scenarios:
>
> Root element of the document ().
>
> - [...]
> - Element with a `position` value `fixed` or `sticky` (sticky for all mobile browsers, but not older desktop).

Inside a stacking context the `z-index` value will influence the stacking order, but not outside

(Same source, emphasis mine)

> Within a stacking context, child elements are stacked according to the same rules previously explained. **Importantly, the `z-index` values of its child stacking contexts only have meaning in this parent.** Stacking contexts are treated atomically as a single unit in the parent stacking context.

I myself find this to be not very useful in most applications.

So you can only have an influence on the stacking order between elements, if those elements share the same stacking context. In your case you must change the HTML code. I reckon, that you don't want that, but you could use pseudo elements to the rescue

```css
.fixed {
  position: fixed;
}

body:after {
  content: '';
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: yellow;
  z-index: 5;
}

.child {
  width: 200px;
  height: 30px;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  background: red;
  z-index: 11;
  color: #fff;
}

.sibling {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  z-index: 10;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="fixed child">
    I want this div to be on top
  </div>
</div>
<div class="fixed sibling">

</div>
```